# Error when when using a struct as function parameter?

Tags: c, function

I made a function that has a pointer and an integer as parameters. Its supposed to print values from a linked list where the pointer points at the first object. The function looks like:

```
void printlist(talstrul *lank, int langd)
    {   int j;
        talstrul *temppek = lank;
            for(j=0; j<langd; j++)
            {   

        printf("%d\n",*temppek);
        temppek = temppek->next;    

        }
    }
```

The error I get is:

```
syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
```

The struct is defined as follows:

```
struct talstrul
{
    int num;
    struct talstrul *next;


};
typedef struct talstrul talstrul;
```

Comment: Do these syntax error messages have line numbers?  Which lines do they indicate?

Comment: actually it works now, I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is almost certainly not actually in that function -- you probably have an unterminated block further up the page.

Comment: youre right, theres something really strange with the code now and now my virusprogram has started removing my .exe files when I compile!!

Comment: It's not your virus program -- your compile is failing so no .exe is being created.

Answer (score 2):

You appear not to have defined `talstrul` (or included the definition here). Perhaps it's a `struct` (but not a `typedef struct`) and you wanted `struct talstrul * lank` and `struct talstrul * temppek = lank;`.

Also this line:

```
printf("%d\n",*temppek);
```

has got to be wrong if `temppek` points to a `struct` as implied by

```
temppek = temppek->next;
```

Comment: now I added how I have defined my struct, is it possible to see the error now?

Answer (score 0):

You want to print the values in the linked list, i.e. the `num` entries of the structs.

```
printf("%d\n",temppek->num);
```

To catch these kinds of errors, compiling with `gcc -Wall` is good practice.

---

Edit:  Indeed, this snippet works fine, and the problem is elsewhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct talstrul {
  int num;
  struct talstrul *next;
} talstrul;

void printlist(talstrul *lank, int langd) {
  int j;
  talstrul *temppek = lank;
  for(j=0; j<langd; j++) {
      printf("%d\n", temppek->num);
      printf("Illogical printing: %d\n",*temppek);
      temppek = temppek->next;
    }
}

int main (void) {
  talstrul *mylank = (talstrul*) malloc (sizeof (talstrul));
  mylank->num = 13;
  mylank->next = NULL;
  printlist(mylank, 1);

  free(mylank);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: that's not the problem, it actually prints the numbers for some illogical reason, maybe because of "%d"? its the functionparameters I have problems with.